# npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

A bit stuck on this one. Taking a Grider course on Docker through Udemy.com.

I just keep getting the following error when I do:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v $(pwd):/app 5932996c40dc

npm ERR! path /app/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-01-30T23_04_17_890Z-debug.log
```

I echo  the command out because I want to see exactly what it is trying to execute and comes back as:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v /mnt/c/projects/courses/docker_kubernetes/frontend:/app 5932996c40dc
```

I run the image without the `-v` so that I can start the container and `exec -it` into it to see what is on the container. It does show everything as it should inside the container. It copied everything into `/app` in the container.

[image]

The command I used to build the image was `docker build -f Dockerfile.dev .` and remove the `node_modules` from the local version.

Here is a copy of my repo that has the Dockerfile and such in it: https://github.com/ishraqiyun77/docker_kubernetes.

Running in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on Windows 10 Pro, `docker-client` is running in WSL, `docker-daemon` is running in VMWare Workstation Player 15. I did make the `.env` for good measure with [`CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true`](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/troubleshooting#npm-start-doesn-t-detect-changes). Not convinced that this config is the issue yet, but who knows, it could be.

Also, there is no `/root/.npm/_logs/2019-01-30T23_04_17_890Z-debug.log` in either the container or the local file system.

I've also changed WSL to instead of having the path `/mnt/c/projects`... to just be `/c/projects`.

Comment: I am pretty sure what is happening is that when you are mounting `$(pwd)` in your Docker run command it is overwriting the directory containing `package.json` with whatever is in the `frontend` directory which likely does not contain a `package.json`. What are you trying to make happen by doing `-v /app/node_modules -v $(pwd):/app`?

Comment: `package.json` is in both the local and the container copy. The `-v /app/node_modules` should just use the container copy of `node_modules` so that the local copy can be deleted. `-v $(pwd):/app` is copying all of the contents of the current directory (`/mnt/c/projects/courses/docker_kubernetes/frontend`) into `/app` in the container. `-v` should be creating a volume so that changes in the local copy are reflected in the container without rebuilding the container.

Comment: I guess I am mostly curious about the contents of `docker_kubernetes/frontend` as it is not present in the Github repository you linked.

Comment: Sorry, that was confusing. I fixed it.

Comment: How did you fix it @sockpuppet?

Comment: @Veeshoo Unfortunately, I didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also taking the Grider course on Docker through Udemy.com. And I met exactly the same problem as you. Since I am using Windows 10 Home Edition, I can't use Docker Desktop (Windows)， instead, I have to use Docker Toolbox.

In my case, I am trying to run:

xwy52@JFC-DELL MINGW64 /d/Git/LearnDevOps/docker/images/frontend (master)
$ docker run -p 3000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v $(pwd):/app 5d83ae77af14

And I met your problem, the solution for me is to configure another shared folder for the default virtual machine in VirtualBox, as seen in below screenshot:
[Configure Shared Folder for Default VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5zpO.jpg)

Comment: Sorry to the really late response following up on this. I tested something similar with Shared Folders in VMware player, but ran into the same errors. I then tried to setup VirtualBox, but can't get WSL to connect to the VM running in VirtualBox. Is there a guide you used to set this up that you can point me to? Weird that docker in VMware is working fine, but not in VirtualBox... test on work and home computers with same issue. This is what I used to setup for VMware and then VirtualBox: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-73-connecting-to-a-remote-docker-daemon

Comment: I am also taking the course, and using too Windows 10 Home Edition, with VirtualBox and Docker Toolbox. I had the same issue. Thanks a lot for your answer it helped me to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding the location where my code is to the Shared Folder via Virtual Box as mentioned by Wenyan but it did not work.

What worked for me is I moved my code to C://Users//{username} as C Drive is mentioned as the storage location in Virtual Box. I had no problems in running docker commands after moving the code.